# Number of values that satisfy $2\sin ^2(x) - 3 = 3 \cos (x), \: 90^{\circ} < x < 270^{\circ} $

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

Graphing this function is difficult as many overlaps exist and finding a viewing window is hard.

What's a good algebraic method to solve this problem?

Comment: Note that $\sin^2 x=1-\cos^2 x$ and then you have a quadratic in $\cos x$

Comment: Hints: $\sin^2x=1-\cos^2x$ and do $y=\cos x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$2\sin^2(x)-3=3\cos(x)\rightarrow 2(1-\cos^2(x))-3=3\cos(x)\rightarrow 2\cos^2(x)+3\cos(x)+1=0\rightarrow (\cos(x)+1)(2\cos(x)+1)=0\rightarrow$

So we can say $\cos(x)=-1$ or $\cos(x)=\frac{-1}{2}$

$\cos(x)=-1\rightarrow x=2k\pi+\pi\rightarrow x=\pi$

$\cos(x)=\frac{-1}{2}\rightarrow x=\frac{2\pi}{3}$ and $x=\frac{4\pi}{3}$

So totally there are three different values for $x$, satisfying the mentioned equation in the intended interval.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

Use the relation $\cos^2x+\sin^2 x=1$ to find a quadratic equation with unkown $\cos x$. Solve it and find the value of $x$ in the desired interval.